# adjust horizontal width when adding content

Tags: jquery, css

with this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atoswchataigner/8QjM7/) example, how do i adjust the body horizontal scroll dynamically when adding more div?

So the div don't jump line and stay on the same line.

I'd rather not use the `white-space: nowrap` but adjust the body dynamically if possible.

Comment: Please ensure you include enough code to replicate the issue directly in your question, links can break and make your question useless to future visitors. Also, it is not clear what `"adjust the body dynamically"` means

Comment: You could add the divs to a wrapper div with a very large width. Ex: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/8QjM7/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add up all .columns width

```
  var totalWidth = 0;
  $.each($('.column'), function(){
     totalWidth += $(this).width();
  });
  $('.divs').width(totalWidth);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8QjM7/8/

Answer (score 1):

You're gonna need that white-space rule. Something like: http://jsfiddle.net/8QjM7/12/

```
.container {
    white-space:nowrap;
}
```

The only other way would be to put them in a container, and use JS to calculate the number of items times their width, and then set that width on the container. Then the container would go off the screen, but the items within would not wrap.

Comment: i don't want to scroll on the container but the body

Comment: Ok, I have updated the link above to scroll the body.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the 'column' divs in another divs. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8QjM7/11/)

Use jQuery to dynamically update the width of the div.

```
var width = $("div.scrollable").width() + 50;
 $("div.scrollable").width(width);
```

Answer (score 0):

first:

wrap all `a` inside `<div class="column">`

then

add `white-space:nowrap;` to `.column`

```
.column {
      display:inline-block;
      height: 50px;
      background-color: #000;
      width: 50px;
      white-space:nowrap; /*added*/
  }
  a {
      display:inline-block; /*added*/
  }
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/8QjM7/9/)